# Link to taxonomie entries Bolt

Tags: bolt-cms

I used the following code to display the category of each entry:

```
{% if record.taxonomy.categorie is defined %}
    {% for tag in record.taxonomy.categorie %}
    {{ tag }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The category is not displayed as a link to a page with only entries in a specific category. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this is with tags from related content.

```
    {% if related.taxonomy.tags is defined %}
        {% for tag in related.taxonomy.tags %}
        <a href="http://example.com/tags/{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

You can try:

```
    {% if record.taxonomy.categorie is defined %}
        {% for categorie in record.taxonomy.categorie %}
        <a href="http://example.com/categorie/{{ categorie }}">{{ categorie }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

hope it helps.